# CSS button hover background style child

Tags: html, css, image, button, background

When someone hovers over a button with a img element inside it, it should have a red background color.

```
<button class="btn-img">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/2/2a/Burj_Al_Arab,_Dubai,_by_Joi_Ito_Dec2007.jpg/220px-Burj_Al_Arab,_Dubai,_by_Joi_Ito_Dec2007.jpg" alt="Dubai" />
</button>


.btn-img {
    display: block;
    width: 160px;
    height: 120px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-img:hover {
    background-color: red;
}

.btn-img:hover img {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/28QEM/

Is this possible? Is it because of the button element, because if a child inside a div has a background color, and the parent background color changes, it basically overwrites the children's background color.

Comment: I'm trying to understand why you're trying to set a background color on an image.  It's an image, not a block container.  Even if you did set the background color to blue, the actual pixels of the image would cover it up.

Comment: @Axel I know, but if the button (which is the parent of the image) has a background style, it should overwrite the actual pixesl of the image?

Comment: @onlineracoon The child element (img) is painted over the parent element.  That is how the CSS stacking model works.

Comment: Are you trying to change the tint of the image? or simply change the color of the background that is rendered behind the image?

Comment: @MarcAudet The images are thumbnails, so when you click on them, you get the full screen version. When you hover over them, they should appear darker (background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .13) on button was my idea to make this possible)

Comment: @onlineracoon I posted a solution to your question, please take a look when you have a moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possible way of getting the effect that you want:

```
<button class="btn-img">
    <div class="img-wrap">
    <img src="image_name.jpg" />
    </div>
</button>
```

and the CSS might look like:

```
.btn-img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: white;
    outline: 1px dotted blue;
}
.btn-img .img-wrap {
    margin: 10px;
}

.btn-img img {
    display: block;
}

.btn-img:hover .img-wrap {
    background-color: black;
}

.btn-img:hover img {
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

**How It Works**

Wrap your image with another `<div>` so that you can control margins and padding more accurately and give you a hook to control the background color behind the image without having the color spill outside of the image itself.

When you trigger `.btn-img:hover`, change the background color of `div.img-wrap` to black and change the opacity of the image to 0.8.  This has the effect of darkening the image.

You can experiment with the effect by trying different background colors for the image wrap element and the degree of opacity.

I think this might work in IE7, but give it try.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/8QMTv/

**And by the way...**

If you are wrapping your image with a link to use some JavaScript type of zoom-view effect (highslider for example), you can replace `<div class="img-wrap">` with a simple `<a>` tag and set its `display: block`.

**Keep in mind...**

Browsers tend to style `<button>` differently from other inline elements like `<span>`, so properties like margin and padding may behave a bit differently than you might expect.

Comment: This answer produces the desired results.